# Apache hosted application not providing cookies

Tags: javascript, django, apache, redirect, cookies

I have a `Django` application hosted in `Apache`. The Application check's for any logged in session by accessing `"user" cookie` in document.cookies(js). if the same is not available .js file will redirect to SSO login page. Once the user enter the credentials "user" cookie gets generated and application shows welcome message by accessing the same.

This was the workflow which was working when i hosted the app in `IIS 8.5`.

Now i hosted the same in `Apache` and now i'm not getting the cookies from the redirect URL. Application is just showing `csrftoken` token. I have hosted the application in port 80 and i tried the same with 8000 also.

PS: Redecoration is completely handled by .js file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What headers are you receiving?  This can be verified with the browser developer tools (Chrome, F12).  In there you see the entire traffic sent from your site, and you can inspect the headers.  One of those should be the cookie you are looking for.  If it is there, ensure it's name is correct, no typo, ...  If it is not there, something in the code is wrong or some condition is not met in the application.  Look at your Apache configuration, verify if mod_headers is loaded.  That is for receiving, read the next comment for sending.

Comment: Receiving == from the application to the browser.  Sending, from the browser.  You want to ensure the browser is sending the cookie back. Again in the headers.  The easiest way is to setup Fiddler to intercept the traffic and look at the headers.  Make sure that the cookie is set for the right domain, and is returned to Apache on new requests.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found that the response code for redirect was 302 which is Found and in the headers i can see the value which i want as well. they are in the below format.

`{
              "name": "Set-Cookie",
              "value": "user=ashwinn; path=/; domain=xyz.com"
            }`